# How to add and display new value to devexpress -wpf gridcontrol comboboxedit column without adding the new value to the combobox datasource

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have gridcontrol combobox column which display list of datatypes from db (eg: varchar(10), int, ... etc))

I'd like the user to be able to change varchar(10) to any other length like varchar(50) , but i don't want to add it to the combobox datasource,
so varchar(50) to be displayed as text but not exist in the combobox items

```
  <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="DataType"
                                Header="Data Type">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ItemsSource="{Binding DataTypes}" DisplayMember="Type" ValueMember="Type"/>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I don't know if that the best solution or is it a good practice to add both column editsettings and edittemplate together or  not but it works anyway

`<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="DataType" 
                                Header="Data Type">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings   DisplayMember="Type" ValueMember="Type"   ItemsSource="{Binding DataTypes}"  />
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <dxe:TextEdit Name="PART_Editor" EditValue="{Binding Data.DataType}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
                    <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <dxe:TextEdit  EditValue="{Binding Data.DataType}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn>`